# Show Versions within the document (IT Hit WebDav)

Tags: webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I am trying to evaluate the ITHit WebDav Server Engine Library as I would like to implement a feature to have the ability to modify different versions within Word.

I am using Word Office 2013 and I am wondering if its possible to show the versions in the word document, under Info tab and then under Versions (next to manage versions button).

I have followed the steps through the wizard to generate the code. I have selected 
1) 'store files and metadata in SQL DB'
2) Delta V support checked 
3) 'auto-put under version control before the first update' and 'allow auto versioning' as checked.

I have tried editing the word file, saving and opening it again. However, I am not able to see the list of versions under the Versions tab. Maybe the versions can only be seen through the AJAX File browser plugin, if thats the case, is there a way to show the different versions available for the document file which was send to the client ? Do I need to extend an interface of IFile or IVersion etc?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft Office is using its proprietary protocol extensions to manage document versions, it is not using WebDAV. As a workaround you can manage versions via Ajax File Browser.

Currently DavEngine class contains AllowOffice12Versioning property which enables versioning in MS Office UI. However this property is experimental and currently marked as internal. It is available for source codes license owners only.