# WebDav Word 2016 Checkin Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I just saw in a video about sharepoint (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhVWtlItL6k Minute 6:50)  that in sharepoint there is a Check In Button. Now my question is is this also possible with ItHit WebDav too? Or is this a button from the Sharepoint Plugin and can only be rebuild with an own plugin?

1. The Video is from Office 2013, I have Office 2016 maybe thats why the Button is not there.
   Otherwise the CheckIn can also be done by closing and saving. But preferably I would like to have an option to Make a Checkin and Signal my Application it should make the Safe a New Version (Optionally with a description input).

[image: Sharepoint Checkin]

2. Also I saw there is the property AllowOffice12Versioning (which said here was experimental:
   [Show Versions within the document (IT Hit WebDav)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998286/show-versions-within-the-document-it-hit-webdav) )

The Versioning Support for DeltaV cannot be reused for word right?
https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/creating_deltav/

Is there any progress on it since 2014 or how is this acutally realized in Office? Does it use any of the WebDav Extenions by Microsoft which I could extend myself if no progres yet? (MS-WDVSE, MS-WDVME, MS-WDV, MS_WDVME...)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, unlike other operations, versioning in MS Office is not using WebDAV, as this post describes: [Show Versions within the document (IT Hit WebDav)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998286/show-versions-within-the-document-it-hit-webdav). MS Office is using its own proprietary protocol to display versions.

One possible solution is implementing check-in/check-out commands and versions list in the [IT Hit WebDAVDrive sample](https://www.userfilesystem.com/examples/webdav_drive/) based on [IT Hit Virtual File System](https://www.userfilesystem.com/) product. This sample works similar to OneDrive (it using the same Windows API) and can automatically lock/unlock documents on the virtual drive, which is very close to check-out/check-in. You potentially can add check-out/check-in/list versions commands to the Windows File Manager context menu as well as attach a hook to file open/close or lock/unlock events in sample code to show a custom user interface.